# Get items by date by clicking day on calendar Javascript Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, backend

I'm developing calendar app with Javascript and Django . I don't now how to display item by date by clicking the day . Is there any solutions ? I have a guess that I need to get elements by ajax on clicking the date .  Here is some code :

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    is_published=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def calendar(request):

item = Item.objects.order_by('-date').filter(is_published=True)
context={
    'item':item,

}
return render(request,'main/calendar.html',context)
```

**Javascript calendar draw methods**

```
  drawAll() {
        this.drawWeekDays();
        this.drawMonths();
        this.drawDays();
        this.drawYearAndCurrentDay();
        this.drawEvents();

    }


    drawYearAndCurrentDay() {
        let calendar = this.getCalendar();
        this.elements.year.innerHTML = calendar.active.year;
        this.elements.currentDay.innerHTML = calendar.active.day;
        this.elements.currentWeekDay.innerHTML = AVAILABLE_WEEK_DAYS[calendar.active.week];
    }

    drawDays() {
        let calendar = this.getCalendar();

        let latestDaysInPrevMonth = this.range(calendar.active.startWeek).map((day, idx) => {
            return {
                dayNumber: this.countOfDaysInMonth(calendar.pMonth) - idx,
                month: new Date(calendar.pMonth).getMonth(),
                year: new Date(calendar.pMonth).getFullYear(),
                currentMonth: false
            }
        }).reverse();


        let daysInActiveMonth = this.range(calendar.active.days).map((day, idx) => {
            let dayNumber = idx + 1;
            let today = new Date();
            return {
                dayNumber,
                today: today.getDate() === dayNumber && today.getFullYear() === calendar.active.year && today.getMonth() === calendar.active.month,
                month: calendar.active.month,
                year: calendar.active.year,
                selected: calendar.active.day === dayNumber,
                currentMonth: true
            }
        });
```

**Here is constructor of class Calendar**

```
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.elements = {
        days: this.getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName('calendar-days'),
        week: this.getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName('calendar-week'),
        month: this.getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName('calendar-month'),
        year: this.getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName('calendar-current-year'),
        currentDay: this.getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName('display_day'),
        currentWeekDay: this.getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName('calendar-left-side-day-of-week'),
        prevYear: this.getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName('calendar-change-year-slider-prev'),
        nextYear: this.getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName('calendar-change-year-slider-next')
    };



    this.date = +new Date();
    this.options.maxDays = 37;
    this.init();
}
 getFirstElementInsideIdByClassName(className) {
    return document.getElementById(this.options.id).getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
}
```

**Here is template**

```
 <div class="right-side">
    <div class="text-right calendar-change-year">
        <div class="calendar-change-year-slider">
            <span class="fa fa-caret-left cursor-pointer calendar-change-year-slider-prev"></span>
            <span class="calendar-current-year"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-caret-right cursor-pointer calendar-change-year-slider-next"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-month-list">
        <ul class="calendar-month"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-week-list">
        <ul class="calendar-week"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-day-list">
        <ul class="calendar-days"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  <h1 class="calendar__heading calendar__heading-2 display_day"></h1>
    <h1 class="calendar__heading calendar-left-side-day-of-week"></h1>
```

**Here is what I want**
[image: Here is what I want]

**Or is there a way to change calendar ? This calendar isn't so necessary**

Comment: well the best imo solution is to get input generating widget like [this](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on input change make ajax call to python function that returns json of the tasks for particular date and render it out. You get best of both worlds frontend) dont have to specify your own callendar backend) site doesn't have to reaload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript code should detect which day you clicked, then it should call an endpoint that will end up in your django view. The view should receive the day and filter the items by date, something like this:

```
Entry.objects.filter(date=selected_day)
```

This should return all the items for a given day.